# Is a Win64 driver (dll which runs perfectly on Win10) compatible to my UWP app on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, uwp, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I am writing an APP UWP on Windows 10 Iot which has to access a 3rd party driver of a UHF reader.

Can I use it on my UWP project? With some extra step or just depend of my vendor to publish a compatible SDK for ARM?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use this driver on Windows 10 IoT platform.You need contact the vendor to provide the compatible SDK for ARM.
Even though [Universal Windows drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/getting-started-with-universal-drivers) enable developers to create a single driver package that runs across multiple different device types, from embedded systems to tablets and desktop PCs, it is necessary to build for ARM after created the driver project.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I found this arcticle that says that I would wrap the dll to my code.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx#BK_StaticLib  . Have you ever see this working fine?

Comment: @Marc, I have read this article yet.But I think the premise is in the same  hardware architectures.The same Visual C++ source code might produce different results on the ARM architecture than it does on x86 or x64 architectures(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/common-visual-cpp-arm-migration-issues). Native is a way/tool to compile the code.